# How to Use Boolean Array to Replace Specific Indices in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, boolean

I have a numpy and a boolean array:

```
nparray = [ 12.66  12.75  12.01  13.51  13.67 ]
bool = [ True False False True True ]
```

I would like to replace all the values in `nparray` by the same value divided by 3 where `bool` is False.

I am a student, and I'm reasonably new to python indexing. Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) with `~` as the negation operator:

```
arr = np.array([12.66, 12.75, 12.01, 13.51, 13.67 ])
bl = np.array([True, False, False, True ,True])

arr[~bl] = arr[~bl] / 3
array([ 12.66      ,   4.25      ,   4.00333333,  13.51      ,  13.67      ])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a really helpful tool.

Comment: It may be worth noting that even though you may set values in the original array while accessing it through Boolean Indexing, this same Boolean Indexing notation cannot be used to  store a view of the original array in a variable. Instead the variable will become a copy of this view. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47671637

Answer (score 2):

naming an array bool might not be the best idea. As ayhan did try renaming it to bl or something else.

You can use numpy.where see the docs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
nparray2 = np.where(bl == False, nparray/3, nparray)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With just python you can do it like this:

```
nparray = [12.66, 12.75, 12.01, 13.51, 13.67]
bool = [True, False, False, True, True]
map(lambda x, y: x if y else x/3.0, nparray, bool)
```

And the result is:

```
[12.66, 4.25, 4.003333333333333, 13.51, 13.67]
```