# numpy boolean indexing selecting and setting

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not very familiar with python. I reading the book 'Python for Data Analysis' recently, and I'm a bit confused about the numpy boolean indexing and setting.
The book said:

> Selecting data from an array by boolean indexing always creates a copy of the data, even if the returned array is unchanged.
>
> Setting values with boolean arrays works in a common-sense way.

And I have tried it as the follow code:

First:

```
data = np.random.randn(7, 4) 
data[data < 0] = 0 # this could change the `data`
```

Second:

```
data = np.random.randn(7, 4) 
copied = data[data < 0]
copied[1] = 1  # this couldn't change the `data`
```

I do not quite understand here, anyone can explain it. In my understanding, `copied` should be pointer to the data[data < 0] slices.

Comment: boolean indexing creates copies, not views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `data[data < 0] = 0` sorta looks like a view being set to `0`, that's not what's actually happening.  In reality, an `ndarray` followed by `=` calls [`__setitem__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__setitem__.html) which handles the piecewise assingment.

When the ndarray is on the other side of the `=`, `__setitem__` isn't called and you assign a copy (as boolean indexing always does), which is independent of the original array.

Essentially:

```
foo[foo != bar] = bar                # calls __setitem__
foo[:2]         = bar                # calls __setitem__
bar             = foo[foo != bar]    # makes a copy
bar             = foo[:2]            # makes a view
```

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb numpy creates a view where possible and a copy where necessary.

When is a view possible? When the data can be addressed using strides, i.e. for example for a 2d array A each `A[i, j]` sits in memory at address `base + i*stride[0] + j*stride[1]`. If you create a subarray using just slices this will always be the case which is why you will get a view.

For logical and advanced indexing it will typically not be possible to find a base and strides which happen to address the right elements. Therefore these operations return a new array with data copied.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sequence of the code:

1. `data = np.random.randn(7, 4)` : Thi step creates an array of size 7 by 4
2. `data[data < 0] = 0` :  makes all the elements in data which are < 0 as 0
3. `copied = data[data < 0]` :  This step generates an empty array as there is no element in data which is < 0, because of step 4
4. `copied[1] = 1` : This step raises an error as copied is an empty array and thus index 1 does not exist